What is the limits for java inline array creation
I was developing a quick fix for a problem in an old project. The problem was that some of the strings taken in the input needed to be converted into different strings before processing the method. Those strings are small between 10 and 30 characters and the "conversion" also small.
No necessity to over-complicate the solution; this is a disposable project, I simply created a Map<String,String> to convert the input into the desired output.
The list of strings to be included in the map was 1300 and because this was supposed to be a quick fix, I didn't want to read a file and make a more complex process. I simply pasted inline into the code:
private static final Map<String, String> translation = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.Entry("a","b"),
    Map.Entry("c","b"),
    Map.Entry("d","b"),
    Map.Entry("e","f"),
    Map.Entry("g","gg"),
    ...

1300 lines of this (this took 1 minute with find/replace). The whole class became 1400 lines 64k characters.
Even though syntax-wise everything was okay, the project stopped compiling. IntelliJ would freeze on "writing classes...". My computer is an i7, 12 cores and 32GB would start boiling like egg, and 20 minutes later the compilation would not finish.
I googled the problem and saw people reporting similar problem under different circumstances.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162091/Writing-classes-when-compiling-is-suddenly-very-very-slow
IntelliJ IDEA: the first compilation takes a lot of time

I tried their fixes without success, I even updated IntelliJ to the latest version but nothing changed.
I removed the giant inline map and everything worked fine, I made the map reading an external file and the whole project worked as expected, but I became very curious.
Why would the JVM be unable to compile the code due a large inline array? I want to make it clear is not a run time problem, it was compile time.
64k characters is not supposed be a huge memory to the heap during compilation, so I keep thinking that there is a hard limit the inline array creation has in the JVM.
Does anyone have a better idea of what is the cause of such kind of problem?

It sounds like a compiler bug in the Intellij compiler.  You could get another data point by trying to compile the class from the command line using javac.  I can't think of a plausible reason for calling this a JVM problem.  The JVM is just a compiler.

There are limits imposed by the Java classfile format, but these should not cause a compiler to run slowly.  If you run into these limits, you should get a compilation error ... quickly.

It's possible the compiler has too little memory to work with. You can set the "process heap size" for the compiler in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler. You can also try to use the Eclipse Java Compiler instead of javac and see if this improves the situation. This can be configured at Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler.

@StephenC, you correct. i was able to compile with maven

(Above I wrote:  "The JVM is just a compiler".  I meant to write : "The JVM is just running a compiler".  The Intellij Java compiler is just a Java program.  And so is javac for that matter.)

The problem is intellij which isn't open source. File a support ticket with them. Javac has no problem with it, until you get to 64k of... something (it's hard to translate directly; the class file limit is, for example, 64k opcodes per method and what you've built is, more or less, a 'method' (it's an instance initializer, which has the same 64k opcode limit). But how many opcodes is a .put chain? 1 to 3 or so. Point is, when you hit this limit, javac will swiftly tell you. Under no circumstances will javac start making your system up and fly out the window.

why would the JVM be unable to compile the code due a large inline array?

You can confirm this by actually using javac and not intellij: This is an incorrect statement. The JVM has no problem compiling this large inline array. More generally 'the JVM' doesn't compile at all, you're mixing up terms. OpenJDK (or just 'a JDK') includes lots of stuff, including a JVM and a compiler. And the compiler runs on the JVM. But saying 'the JVM is unable to compile' is just weird, especially when the actual problem is that IntelliJ's code analyser (used to power its intelligent tools) is the one that chokes on this input, not the compiler.

"The compiler runs on the JVM"? I thought javac is written in C++, isn't it?

@Sweeper As far as I'm aware, most of javac is written in Java itself these days.

@Sweeper No, it is written in java and has been for decades. Sources to OpenJDK 1.7's javac - and java 1.7 is decades old.

@Sweeper even back in Java 1.0.2 the javac binary was just a launcher for the sun.tools.javac.Main class.

@Sweeper I think you might be thinking of jikes - now dead by nearly 2 decades. A java compiler written in C++. The fastest java compiler out there by a significant margin (~4x faster) is ecj (eclipse's compiler, and available standalone). It's written in java.

IntelliJ IDEA is in fact open source (not everything, but basic Java support is): https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community Highlighting the editor is IntelliJ IDEA specific, but plain javac is used for compilation.

The question’s code is not a put chain but a varargs method invocation. The code has to push the arguments to Map.entry, perform the Map.entry invocation, put the array index, and store the argument into the array. The overhead is around 12 bytes per argument, which yields a theoretical limit around 5000. However, in my test, javac needed several minutes to compile an example with 1000 arguments. This indicates a non-linear overhead which makes the OP’s observation plausible. A similar thing happened with the maximum number of constructors…

The cause of the performance problem is probably the (apparently expensive) type inference on every Map.entry() call. This can be avoid by adding
type arguments to the method calls:
private static final Map<String, String> translation = Map.ofEntries(
          Map.<String, String>entry("a","b"),
          Map.<String, String>entry("c","b"),
          Map.<String, String>entry("d","b"),
          Map.<String, String>entry("e","f"),
          Map.<String, String>entry("g","gg"),
...

This can be done with a simple search and replace.
Another option is to initialize the map like this, which has the same effect.
  private static final Map<String, String> translation = new HashMap<>();
  static {
    translation.put("a", "b");
    translation.put("c", "b");
    translation.put("d", "b");
    translation.put("e", "f");
    translation.put("g", "gg");


I will test the type inference thing latter, but the second option is not exact same effect as Map.ofEntries is immutable while hashmap isn't. And maybe i'm too fannact for single line code so breaking it into a static block kind of turns me off
